# how to reload the parent of an iframe without reloading it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

Please How could I reload the parent of an `iframe` **without** refreshing this `iframe` itself. i.e Prevent the refresh of the `iframe` which handle the reload of the parent.

Comment: This question is not javascript, jquery, jsf or iframe related!

Comment: what kind of question so?

Comment: You'd sort of have the same 'problem' when you'd write:  "How to reload the (whole) parent of a div but not leave the div it self in place". So the iframe tag is unrelated. And since there is no javascript, jquery or jsf in your question, none of the tags are related (and even if there is some jsf in your question, it might still not be part of the 'problem'). So all that 'remains is [tag:html] and maybe [tag:ajax].

Answer (score 3):

The only solution is to not fully reload the parent but all individual parts of it (via 'ajax') except the part you don't want to be reloaded (the `iframe` in your case).

How to technically do that is beyond this question and very much depending on the technology you use. Most frameworks that have some sort mechanism to update parts of a page via 'ajax' have the option to identify what parts to update. And there are many Q/A in stackoverflow about updating parts of pages related to these different frameworks.

But honestly, I think there is some sort of design flaw in your application since it is a very uncommon use case.